# Windows 8: how to modify an default firewall rule?

Tags: windows-8, windows-firewall

On one Windows 8 computer I modified the Remote Desktop Port. The default port is 3389. I set it to 1234.

Now I want to tell the firewall to open the 1234 port.
I could just create a new firewall rule for TCP 1234. Or create a rule alowing svchost.exe to use whatever port.
But it may be better to modify the default rule. But some properties are not modifiable.
Even a copied/pasted default rule is not modifiable.

Is there a way to modify a default firewall rule on Windows 8 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to do it:

The default rules are stored in `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Defaults\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules]` (used when you reset the rules to default values).

The current rules are stored in `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules]` (including the rules you created).

Just do a search inside the required key, and replace the desired settings.
To know the syntax, create a similar rule and look at its structure.

Comment: I am not seeing rules created using COM here

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. The default rules are defined based on the ports assigned to the specific services. You'll have to open the port manually for the 1234 port you're using.